# jQuery ajax call with Ajax() function doesn't work

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

This is the code of index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function () {    
            jQuery('#city').change(function() {
                var city = jQuery('#city').val();           
                var data = "city=" + city; 
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: 'page.php', 
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data){ jQuery("#my_div").html(data); }
                });             
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id='city'>  
        <option value='Paris'>Paris</option>
        <option value='London'>London</option>
        <option value='Rome'>Rome</option>
    </select>   
    <div id='my_div'>
        <?php require_once('page.php'); ?>      
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

And page.php:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['city'])) echo 'you selected '.$_GET['city']; ?>
```

Selected a city should display 'you selected ' then the name of the city. But it doesn't do anything..

Comment: You need to actually pass the data to your page.  data: data -> data: city

Comment: You're not sending the data.

Comment: For my information, is the html parameter some kind of implicit result parameter in function(data){ jQuery("#my_div").html(html); ?

Comment: @ jbl... no. Its just a variable that most developers name according to the type of response the script receives. I commonly use $.post which does not require defining the data type so using the var name to distinguish is common practice in this case. For example, if I'm returning json, I'll typically name this var `json`. If html, then its named `html`, etc.

Comment: @zgr024 thx. But my question came from the fact that the first person to answer did not point the issue with the html var, I was wondering if I had not missed some magic hidden feature of jQuery.ajax ( but that was just another typo)

Answer (score 2):

you are not sending the data... data is undefined here... change your code `var city = "city=" + city;` to `var data= "city=" + city;`.. adn you are getting your response as data.. so replace

```
jQuery("#my_div").html(html);
```

with

```
jQuery("#my_div").html(data);
```

try this

```
 jQuery('#city').change(function() {
            var city = jQuery('#city').val();           
            var data= "city=" + city; //<--here
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'page.php', 
                type: 'GET',
                data: data,
                success: function(data){ jQuery("#my_div").html(data); } //<--here
            });             
        });
```

Comment: This and `.html(data);` instead of `.html(html);` in the success handler

Comment: Thanks, it now works. But amazingly, it does NOT work if the code is a WP page template. Here's the code working well in a isolated directory: http://46.20.119.207/~asuntosf/wordpress_test/wp-content/themes/test_ajax/test_ajax/. Now, EXACTLY the same code (copy/past + insertion of WP page template comments at the beginning of the file) as a WP template page : http://46.20.119.207/~asuntosf/wordpress_test/?page_id=13 . Doesn't work. This is completely mind-blogging to me. Perhaps I should create a new question for this issue?

Comment: yes... that would be better..anyways welcome... happy coding. :)

Answer (score 1):

you could use shorthand... but the real issue here is two variables are "undefined". 
The html variable is not defined, nor was the data variable as previously mentioned.

Give this a shot

```
   $('#city').change(function() {
        var data= "city=" + $('#city').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'page.php', 
            type: 'GET',
            data: data,
            success: function(html){ 
                $("#my_div").html(html); 
            }
        });             
    });
```